# Check what proxies are used in Requests module in Python3

Tags: python, python-requests

How to check what proxies are used by Python3 `Requests` module?

I have verified (from responses) that when you set http proxy in system configuration on MacOS but not set the http_proxy environment variable it will also be automatically used by Requests. It seems like it will use the proxies that `urllib.request.getproxies()` return, but I'm not sure because the [document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) only says that

> You can also configure proxies by setting the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

and it seems there aren't any descriptions on system proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
requests.utils.getproxies()
```

or

```
requests.utils.get_environ_proxies(url)
```